# DefaultType directive in apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4

We have just migrated from Apache 2.0.53 to Apache 2.4
Everything works perfectly for html/js/css files etc.

But we have a number of endpoints on our servers which return plain text.
For example - an endpoint would return -

```
RIL~Reliance Industries~1234~abcd
```

By default the response for these do not contain any "content-type" but I am expecting "text/plain"

In Apache 2.0.53 we were using

```
DefaultType text/plain
```

But in Apache 2.4 , this directive is disabled. (Ref:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#defaulttype)

I have a large number of requests and want a generic solution that I can apply to my apache so that if there is no content-type provided, then it should send "text/plain"

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
ForceType text/plain
```

This worked for me....

Comment: As noted in the [other answer](https://serverfault.com/a/887119/49157), `ForceType` overrides the `Content-Type` header on _all responses_. So, you will probably want to use this with a _condition_ of some kind.

Comment: This will probably break something else... css rss pdf video, etc... See my reply below

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use `ForceType text/plain` to set the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain`. This will make **all responses** return `text/plain`, however.

A very specific problem in using `ForceType` is that it breaks `mod_mime`'s file extension detection. For example, files requested with `.css` or `.js` extensions won't have their `Content-Type` set to `text/css` or `application/javascript` and will instead have it set to `text/plain`: probably not what you want.

As noted in [a chain on the apache mailing list](https://lists.gt.net/apache/users/443558), the reason why `DefaultType` was removed is because they are now recommending that the browser do the sniffing to figure out the content-type. If you're upgrading from apache 2.2 to 2.4, then you should try to just use it without adding it back in.

Comment: +1 for the extra context and suggestion to try removing `DefaultType`.

Answer (score 4):

Using ForceType at global level (meaning on all requests) will probably break other things like css, js...

This is common problem when serving path with html content having-no-extension *(.html)*

Simplified as not having a dot in the name:

```xml
<FilesMatch "^[^.]+$">
    ForceType text/html
</FilesMatch>
```

Could be smarter to only check on last 5 characters:

```xml
<FilesMatch "^[^.]{0,5}$">
    ForceType text/html
</FilesMatch>
```