# How to set default content type for all non-error apache responses?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I want all apache non-error responses to be sent with content-type `'application/json; charset=UTF-8'`. How do I make it?

I've tried adding:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    AddType 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
</VirtualHost>
```

But this requires specifying file extension, I don't want to bind to file extensions since I'm not requesting specific files, but resources like this:

```
http://my.domain.com/rest/articles/
```

I've also tried `DefaultType` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      DefaultType 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
</VirtualHost>
```

but this doesn't seem to be working - `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8` is returned. Am I missing something?

Comment: The `DefaultType` directive is "disabled" on Apache 2.4. See this related question for more info: https://serverfault.com/questions/622096/defaulttype-directive-in-apache-2-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Apache's `ForceType` directive, explained in [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype). You have to use it in a Directory, Location, or Files context. For JSON, you'd want to use `ForceType application/json`. So, in your vhost, you'd likely want to do something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     <Location />
          ForceType application/json
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```